# Convert a long phrase to its acronym (anagram)

Tags: javascript

Given an array of words, print all anagrams together.

> Note: An anagram of a string is another string that contains same characters, only the order of characters
>   can be different. For example, “abcd” and “dabc” are anagram of each other.
>   For example, if the given array is
>   Input:

```
["cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"],
```

Output: then output may be

```
“cat tac act dog god”
```

```js
let a = ["cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"];

function anagram(array) {
  var organized = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var word = array[i].split('').sort().join('');
    if (!organized.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
      organized[word] = [];
    }
    organized[word].push(array[i]);
    organized[word].join();
  }
  return organized;
}

console.log(anagram(a));
```

my output is not as what required i don't know what to add so i can make the array form a join string of words in order.

Comment: If you change `var organized = []` to `var organized = {}`, it returns an object with grouped anagrams

Comment: yes i have done that but i want my output to be a string printed with all anagrams together

Comment: `Object.values(organized).flat().join(', ')`